# How to handle success with 'if - else' in ajax call and response?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a written code in AJAX which checks whether password exists or not. if yes it sends "OK" as output else "Incorrect " as output . i want to success handler in AJAX call's response to do task based on that. How can handle it? I want if password is correct , to remove Attribute of disabled in a form element else i want i want that form element's attribute remained back as disabled.
   AJAX code goe like this :

```
$("#currentpassword").keyup(function() {
    var name = $(this).val();

    if (name.length > 5) {
        $("#result").html('checking...');



        $.ajax({

            type: 'POST',
            url: 'checkPassword.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                if (data == "1") {
                    $("#result").html(data);
                    $("#newpassword").removeAttr("disabled");
                    $("#confirmpassword").removeAttr("disabled");

                } else {
                    $("#result").html(data);

                }
            }


        });
        return false;
    } else {
        $("#result").html('');
    }
});
```

checkpassword php file looks like below :

```
 <?php

  include_once 'includes.php';




// Submitted form data 

         $currentpassword=$_POST['currentpassword'];


        $result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `password`='$currentpassword' AND `username`='$session_username'");
$row = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($row!=1) {
    echo "<span style='color:red;'>Incorrect Password !!!</span>";;

}
else {
    echo "OK";
}

// Output status

 ?>
```

Comment: instead of `if (data == "1") {`, go for `if (data == "OK") {` as you are returning `OK` from your PHP code.

Comment: your php never sends back `"1"` so the ajax callback is not looking for the correct response - it either sends `OK` or `<span style='color:red;'>Incorrect Password !!!</span>`

Comment: @vijayP yeah i tried if (data == "OK") still it wasn't working

Comment: @RamRaider so what should be correct way of returning value from php in my php code case?

Comment: add `dataType:text` in ajax

Comment: @guradio now its not entering AJAX '.ajax' ,its stuck with '$("#result").html('checking...');' after i added 'dataType:text' before 'success: '

Comment: you are getting error need `,`

Comment: i included , still wasn't working

Comment: @user21488 can you check for error or can you check what ajax is returning also can you update the OP post the code you are using

Answer (score 0):

The Good way is The PHP file should look like this

```
<?PHP

header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');

include_once 'includes.php';

$currentpassword=$_POST['currentpassword'];

$result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `password`='$currentpassword' AND `username`='$session_username'");
$count  = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($count! = 1) {
   header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized', true, 401);
    echo json_encode('In Correct Password');
} else {
    header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found', true, 404);
    echo json_encode('Not Found');
}
```

And your Jquery will be

```
$.ajax({

            type: 'POST',
            url: 'checkPassword.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
               // Only 200 comes here
            }, error(jqXHR, exception) {
              // All errors except 200 comes here.
            }


        });
```

Hope this helps

Comment: function(data) {
        // Only 200 comes here

       $("#result").html(data);
             $("#newpassword").removeAttr("disabled");
             $("#confirmpassword").removeAttr("disabled");
     }, error(jqXHR, exception) {
      $("#result").html(data);
     } i have changed it ..is it correct ? @Reiah Paul Sam

Comment: @user21488 how come `var data` is visible inside `error()` function ??